# Is there a way to save pdf's for embed in HTML?

Tags: html, pdf, display

I made a page where I want to show a pdf file. I figured that I had to use embed for this. I tested it out with this PDF:

```
<embed src='https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa06/cse120/lectures/120-fa06-l13.pdf' type='application/pdf'>
```

And it worked just fine, this displays my pdf correctly (with the use of some CSS)
But now I wanted to test this with my own PDF files, and I dont want to store them in my local host, I want to be able to get it from an online storage, like dropbox.

When I tried this, it didnt work, because dropbox files are secured, and I also tried Google Drive, but this did not give me a PDF link. Also the PDF reader had to much functionality to it, and I want the embed to open the PDF in the standard PDF reader.

Is there any way to fix this issue? Like a online storage that works, or should I use a different method for this?

Comment: you can embed pdf from google drive using `<iframe>`

Comment: I used my iframe like this:

Comment: <iframe src='link' type='application/pdf'></iframe>

Comment: it doesnt show anything in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Use `iframe` and serve pdf from google drive and for doing so go like:

Select a uploaded pdf file you want to embed then:

> Right click > Preview > Expand three dot menu at top left > Open in a
>   new window.
>
> Now click three dot menu again at top left > Select Embed item...

Copy the embed code and use it wherever you want.

**Note**: Pdf file access must be set to public.

Comment: Is that a common issue or not?

Comment: what problem with loading ?

Comment: it says "oops! there are problems when loading the page"

Comment: Make sure the pdf you are trying to embed is publicly available

Comment: I clicked share and I selected everyone can read, but it still shows me the error, but when I click on the hyperlink, it brings me to the actual link, and that works.